# Neo4j - Importing a Database of fraud detection

Tags: database, neo4j, fraud-prevention

Hello i'm trying to deploy the Fraud Detection Use case that was shared in NEO4j use cases 
Following this link: https://neo4j.com/graphgist/credit-card-fraud-detection

To get deeper in the data I want to work with the database that was shared in the link
https://www.dropbox.com/s/4uij4gs2iyva5bd/credit%20card%20fraud.zip

I don't know how to load it since there is no .csv file just .db with the same structure of system and neo4j Databases, 
I have tried to create a Database and connect it to the path of the fraud detection file,

Anyone can help me please to work with this database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Neo4j Desktop:

1. Go to the management tab of your graph
2. Click "Open terminal"
3. Locate the folder `data/databases/`
4. Copy the content of the folder you downloaded from Dropbox into `data/databases/fraud.db`
5. Back to the management tab, go to the settings tab and identify the line:

   ```
   #dbms.active_database=graph.db
   ```
6. Change this line to:

   ```
   dbms.active_database=fraud.db
   ```
7. Restart your database

In case of error, go back to the settings and uncomment:

```
#dbms.allow_upgrade=true
```

Comment: Thanks a lot,  I have already tried that and couldn't find the line :
#dbms.active_database=graph.db in the settings
I have modified this line but still it's not orking
# Paths of directories in the installation.
#dbms.directories.data=data

Comment: Hum, indeed the above procedure is perhaps not valid for Neo4j 4. I've tried with neo4j 3.x but got migration errors. I have the impression this fraud DB is quite old (2014 (?))

Comment: Yes it is an old db dated from 2013, I have tried to look for a more recent database but could not find.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response I have been exploring all the solutions proposed lately, but they were all applicable to the earlier versions of Neo4j.
So for the latest version, do you have an idea how can i run other Databases ?

Comment: Hi, I am afraid I can't help you on this unfortunately. If you don't get your answer here, you can try asking on the Neo4j community forum. Good luck!